# How can I run background task in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I saw that I could run background tasks by using `nohup node index.js`.
My problem is related with following source.
https://github.com/Palpasa/Node-Express-Seed.
In this source, `package.json` file contains `nodemon` and it is working when I start the server with `npm start`.
For now, I tried to run the server in background.
But it is crashing with following error.

```
[nodemon] 1.14.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
/home/tom/Documents/work/wallet/app/app.js:3
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How can I run this server in background?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run several screens on your putty.

screen

Then you will have one screen.
You can now run your node instance on this screen.

This screen is alive all the time.

Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to go out of the screen.

Your node instance is now always alive even you quit putty.

Answer (score 1):

[Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) is what you would want to use.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const otherScript = spawn('node', ['script-you-wanna-run.js']);

otherScript.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Comment: I don't need child process.
I am going to run this server permanently in anyway
Are there any way to run without nodemon?
If I remove the nodemon,  it will show error in that seed project

Comment: TMUX or PM2 would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `ES-2015` babel preset to transpile the import statements. If you don't need the ES6 import specifically, just use `require`

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
```

On another note you can try using Forever npm package. This let's you start the node server in the background

[**FOREVER**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

```
npm install -g forever
forever start server.js

// To run on a custom po
PORT=3000 forever start server.js
```

Comment: I tried as your help
It is working but I can't find port number

Comment: I think it runs on `3000` if not try `8081`. If not try this for custom port number `PORT=3000 forever start server.js `

Comment: still not running.
I set PORT=3500 forever start app.js

Comment: Did you resolve your `import` error? What does the stacktrace say when you run `node server.js`? If it's the same as before then modify your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run `nodemon` in the background (i.e `nohup npm start` <=> `nohup nodemon app.js`), nodemon supposed to be used for development environment, it let you see what changes are made on files during development, if you are looking for running express app in production, Then you should use a [process manager](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/pm.html), it restarts the app automatically when it crashes, or when changes are made, read this [article](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/pm.html) for more information. Here is an example using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) module:

Install pm2:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

Run app:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Comment: I want to run this app for production.
I tried to use `pm2` but node process is not running

Comment: Try to use `pm2 start ./build/bin/www`